# Sharepoint 2010 is changing my internet hyperlink column url to my intranet url, why?

Tags: sharepoint, url, intranet

I have a content type with a hyperlink column.

If I create a page based on that content type and point the hyperlink field to a document in a library on our public url (eg: `http://internet.test.com/documents/test.pdf`) the url gets changed to point to the intranet/administration site (eg: `http://**edit**.test.com/documents/test.pdf`) which then fires the windows login prompt.

Why is Sharepoint changing the url of the item and how do I make it stay as `http://internet.test.com/documents/test.pdf` so anyone can download it.

Some people have mentioned Alternate Access Mapping, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Those people are probably right. There's an interesting video on this site:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff679917.aspx